# Help me to understand some lines of tex code about class specific pagestyle

Tags: header-footer, pagestyle

I'm writing my thesis template and I'm currently taking inspiration from different types of tex templates already available online.
After redefining the header/footer of the pagestyle I'm stuck dealing with the following code meaning I'm litteraly not able to understand their meaning: I don't know what they do and if they are necessary to me.

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\newcommand{\blank@p@gestyle}{empty}
\newcommand{\chapter@p@gestyle}{plain}
\NewDocumentCommand{\blankpagestyle}{ m }{%
    \ClassWarning{\classname}{\string\blankpagestyle\space is
    obsolete,\MessageBreak use \string\setblankpagestyle \space  instead}\renewcommand{\blank@p@gestyle}{}{#1}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setblankpagestyle}{ m }{\renewcommand{\blank@p@gestyle}{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setchapterpagestyle}{ m }{\renewcommand{\chapter@p@gestyle}{#1}}

\DeclareDocumentCommand\cleardoublepage{}{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
    \hbox{}
    \thispagestyle{\blank@p@gestyle}
    \newpage
    \if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi%
}
```

If you need more information or context, please let me know.
Thanks

Comment: You need to be more specific than that or your question will be closed as opionbased.

Comment: I edited my question adding that I'm not able to understand what these lines do: their meaning. Are they necessary (layour breaking) or are just preferences of the coder?

Comment: Again we have no idea. Note that many templates found online are of a very poor quality. Often because they lack documentation or because they use constructions that are no longer recommended. Out of context I have no idea what these do. I usually advise our students to start with the memoir class and build their thesis from that. (full disclaimer, I maintain memoir) and not use a random thesis template from the internet.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your concerning. I will look into the memoir class you mentioned. I was using the standard book class extended with some scr/KOMA script options (I'm not sure if this is the correct terminology: I'm still learning). Thank you anyway and have a good day.

Comment: KOMA is just as good a starting point as memoir, it is just when people add stuff on top with out documentation that things get confusing. I would not are so much about the template and instead focus on writing the contents, then the various layouting stuff can be adjusted later.

Comment: Just don't use he class as inspiration. Don't even assume the code is good or does make any sense at all. In many places, it doesn't. The class is just not that goo.

Comment: If the last page of a chapter is empty on the left side, it will still display the running header by default. Some people want it another way. Some people want to have a different pagestyle when a chapter starts (`plain` would be default). The lines you show enable the user to *"easily"* change the default. Do you need that? Certainly not. Is it useful? Can be. Is it documented somewhere? No! Everything that is not documented properly, could have just as well gone into the trash bin.

Comment: As a template user, writing a thesis, you shouldn't even bother to look into the class file. You are not allowed to make any changes anyway without taking into account other stuff to follow the class license.

Comment: https://github.com/johannesbottcher/MDT-Quick-Manual#occasional-blank-pages-appearing